# Jedi: Force-controlled clothing?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force

I wear a Jedi robe (all right, it's a dressing gown) and I have noticed, during my fearless expeditions into the kitchen, that both the hood and sleeves are a bit of a hindrance in everyday activities.

In-universe, do Jedi manipulate their attire using the force? This is good mindfulness training, if nothing else. Otherwise, they'd constantly be lifting their hood too look for things on the top shelf, or holding their sleeve out of the way with their other hand whilst trying to make sandwiches, for example.

---

In other words, do Jedi use the Force to control clothing that would otherwise be a hindrance (wide capes, for instance)?

Comment: If they're a hindrance making sarnies, imagine how much of a bother they'd be fighting with a lightsaber!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet funny you use the force to make your sarnies?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I don't, Zariel does. Or Jedi do. I don't know.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Why else do you think Yoda had Luke practice balancing stones on top of each other? Basic Padawan skills!

Comment: Alternative solution: make sandwiches with the force or sense the location of what you want then force-pull is down to you

Comment: I imagine they only have their hoods up in inclement weather, such as rain or extreme cold.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Most lightsaber fighters have their sleeves cut above the hand, and/or tuck them into their gloves, bracers or other hand/wristwear.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

But notice how during lightsaber battles (such as in the videos below), loose sleeves generally don't fall down to expose your arm when they are raised. This suggests that Force users have trained to use the Force to keep them from being a hindrance like you said (until they become reflex), or Star Wars clothes are designed to be fastened internally so they don't fall (hey, how come nobody does that on Earth?)

But as a rule, the big sleeves always lose.

No wonder the Jedi are wiped out...

The one time they did win though, it's because they stripped.

Comment: The Jedi clearly need a [master outfit designer](http://i1190.photobucket.com/albums/z457/selene0789/NoCapes_zps82c1bcc0.jpg).

Comment: @lazarusL Except as the first image shows the only character who wears a cape survives both the original and prequel trilogies. Or at least dies right at the end of Jedi, and not due to a cape malfunction.

Comment: Lando was in the prequels?